# Telegram compiled from source crashing, jni error after changing the package name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, telegram

I downloaded Telegram's source code from the official repository here:
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

I wanted to compile the app and use it besides the official telegram in my phone so I changed the package name from `org.telegram.messenger` to `org.telegram.myname` then I had to change some of the references in the java code so I did.

Now the app compiles fine but it crashes with this error:

> E/art: No implementation found for void org.telegram.myname.NativeLoader.init(java.lang.String, boolean) (tried Java_org_telegram_myname_NativeLoader_init and Java_org_telegram_myname_NativeLoader_init__Ljava_lang_String_2Z)

I know this is because jni uses the package name to reference the java methods from c++ code and I can probably fix it by changing the native code and compiling it to `.so` files.

BUT, this shouldn't be this hard to get Telegram up and running from the source code. Am I missing something? Is there an easy way doing all this? Or is this just normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's how I got it working. In a clean source code without changing any of the XMLs, I added `applicationID` to the `build.gradle` and `applicationIdSuffix` to each build type (debug, release, foss).

Now it compiles without an error and I can install it besides the original app.

Comment: Hi where can we find this applicationId

Answer (score 1):

The failure is because the Java class that uses the native library was renamed (moved from `org.telegram.messenger` package to `org.telegram.myname`), but the corresponding native methods were not renamed.

You could rename these function in the C++ files, this should be quite easy. But there was no need to do so. You did not need to rename the Java package in the first place. There is no requirement that the Java classes of your app use the package name used in the app manifest.

Changing the package name in **AndroidManifest.xml** may require using full names for the activities and services, and fixing some **import** paths in Java. But it is much less change than to move all Java classes to the new package name.

Comment: I didn't change the package, I just modified AndroidManifest.xml and some imports. Do you think Android Studio might have done that automatically?

Comment: It could easily change Java automatically, never tried this route personally. But moving the Java classes back to `org.telegram.messenger` should be also handled easily.

Comment: OK I did something else. I got it back to the original code and just changed the ApplicationID in the `gradle.build`. Now I can compile it with a different package name, no errors. But I can't install it besides the original Telegram app! any idea why that is?

Comment: I believe that the Package name in AndroidManifest still prevails. If AS is so insistent on chain rename, you can always use a simple text editor to change the package only.